# Java SQL connection, select query

Tags: java, sql

I created this method, but when i try to call the method it returns a null pointer exception. Can anybody tell me what's wrong? help me please

```
public Talent SearchTalentQuery(int talentID){
    String SearchTalentString = "SELECT * FROM TALENT WHERE TALENTID = "+talentID+";";
    Talent talent=null;
    try{
        //error in select query
        if(getOracleXEConnection()!=null){

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SearchTalentString);                       
                   while( rs.next()){
                   talent.setTalentName(rs.getString("talentname"));
                   talent.setTalentFocus(rs.getString("maintalentfocus"));
                   talent.setTalentNationality((rs.getString("nationality")));
                   talent.setTalentGroup(rs.getString("talentgroup"));
                   talent.setTalentHiredate(rs.getString("hiredate"));
                   talent.setTalentAge(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("age")));
                   talent.setTalentID(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("talentid")));
                   }

            rs.close();
            statement.close();
            conn.close();


            return talent;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException | NumberFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your whole code does not initialize memory for talent object. you need to initialize memory for talent object.

use:
Talent talent= new Talent();
at the place of
Talent talent = null;

It might solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You're not *instantiating* a `Talent` object to assign to.

```
Talent talent=null;
...
talent.setTalentName(...
```

To address your comment, you're *initialising* the `talent` reference to a null pointer. You need to *instantiate* an object and point to it in order to call methods on it.

Depending on your constraints etc. your method will likely want to return this `Talent` object, or create a new one through each iteration and return a collection of these.

Comment: isn't is initialized on this statement: `Talent talent=null;` ?

Comment: `Talent talent=null` This is to `null`, no object, how can you call method on it? it is `null`. This is what `NullPointerException` called

Answer (score 3):

Just instantiate your talent object at the beginning of the while block

...

```
while( rs.next()){ 
 talent = new Talent(); //or whatever
 talent.setTalentName(rs.getString("talentname"));
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate talent, but also you should really use PreparedStatement as this code is extremely open to SQL injections...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Finally, for convention, searchTalentString should start with a lower case character (and maybe be made final)...

```
String searchTalentString = "SELECT * FROM TALENT WHERE TALENTID = "+talentID+";";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
String SearchTalentString = "SELECT * FROM TALENT WHERE TALENTID = "+talentID+";";
Talent talent=new Talent();
```

Or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
   public void Insert(){
            try {
                Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
                Statement consulta = conn.createStatement();
                String query = "SELECT * FROM coches";
                System.out.println("Fecha de entrada");
                String fe = scanner.next();
                System.out.println("Fecha de salida");
                String fs = scanner.next();
                
                ResultSet rs = consulta.executeQuery(query);
                int i = 1;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(i + "," + rs.getString("matricula") + "," + rs.getString("marca") + "," + rs.getString("modelo")); 
                    i++;
                }
                System.out.println("Selecciona el numero del coche");
                int n = scanner.nextInt();
                rs.absolute(n);
               
                
                sta.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO reparaciones (fecha_entrada,fecha_salida,coche) VALUES ('"+ fe + "', '" + fs + "', '" + rs.getString("matricula") + "');");
                
                System.out.println("Reparación insertada, indica los materiales usados");           
               
                String nombre = "";
                
                do{
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Nombre :");
                    scanner.nextLine();
                    nombre = scanner.nextLine();                           
                    if(!nombre.equals("")){
                        System.out.println("Cantidad :");
                        int cant = scanner.nextInt();
                        System.out.println("Precio :");
                        int prec = scanner.nextInt();
                        sta.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO materiales (nombre,cantidad,precio,reparacion) VALUES ('"+ nombre + "', '" + cant + "', '" + prec +  "', '" + n + "');");
                    }
               } 
               while(!nombre.equals(""));   
                sta.close();
                rs.close();
                consulta.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("ERROR:al hacer un Insert");         
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void Delete(){
            try {
                Statement baja = conn.createStatement();
                Statement consulta = conn.createStatement();
                String query = "SELECT * FROM materiales";
                ResultSet rs = consulta.executeQuery(query);
                int i = 1;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt("id") + "," + rs.getString("nombre"));
                    i++;
                }
                System.out.println("Elige una opcion");
                int opc = scanner.nextInt();
               
                String query2 = "SELECT reparacion FROM materiales WHERE id = " + opc;
                ResultSet rs2 = consulta.executeQuery(query2);
                if(rs2.next()){
                  if(rs2.getInt("reparacion")!=0){
                    System.out.println("No es posible darlo de baja");
                  }
                  else{
                    String queryBaja = "DELETE FROM materiales WHERE id ='" + opc +"'";
                    baja.executeUpdate(queryBaja);
                    System.out.println("Eliminado con exito");  
                  }
                }
    
                
                baja.close();
                consulta.close();
                rs.close();
                rs2.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("ERROR:al hacer un delete");         
                ex.printStackTrace();           
            }
        }
```